# insanely large GDT blocks with mdadm partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid, ext4, mdadm

I have a 4 drive USB3.0 external ext4 mdadm lvm RAID-5 array connected to my Ubuntu 16.10 box (ripped from a broken Synology). Disk manager shows the array is fine and all the logical partitions are visible, however only 2 (of the 5) mount properly. The other 3 throw exit status 32 errors and `dmesg` says:

> Number of reserved GDT blocks insanely large: 8189

A filesystem check on the partitions gives

> Corruption found in superblock. (reserved_gdt_blocks = 8189)

I've attempted to restore the superblocks on the partitions from backups using the `e2fsck -b` command but none of them work, but I'm not sure that's the real issue, Ubuntu isn't happy with the GDT block size.

Comment: parted result:
Error: /dev/md127: unrecognised disk label
Model: Linux Software RAID array (md)
Disk /dev/md127: 8987GB
Sector size: (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk flags:

Comment: mdadm --examine --scan /dev/md127 gives no result

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a cap was put on the number of reserved GDT blocks allowed in all LTS releases of Ubuntu. This apparently has something to do the stability or reliability of accessing such drives.

I am not sure how to override this limit, or even if overriding the limit was possible. Instead, I used an older Unsupported Release of Ubuntu that did not have the GDT Block Restriction, such as Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf, to access the files on my Synology RAID drive.

The discussion from [[Mount] GDT blocks insanely wide. (resolved)](https://forums.archlinux.fr/viewtopic.php?t=18503) tipped me off as to what was happening.